# MSBuild command line to build VC++ project

Tags: c++, visual-c++, command-line

I'm trying to use MSBuild command to build a VC++ project. Then it invokes VCBuild to build VC++ project. But it says " Project-to-project references between VC++ projects (.VCPROJ) and C#/VB/VJ# projects (.CSPROJ, .VBPROJ, .VJSPROJ) are not supported by the command-line build systems when building stand-alone VC++ projects"
Is there any other way to do this ? Of course it's possible to build the solution, but I want to build the project only.